# Action delegate -declaration correction

Tags: c#, delegates

According to the definition of action delegate it does not return value but passes value.

I pass the value to Console.WriteLine( )

```
Action<int> an = new Action<int>(Console.WriteLine(3000));
```

But still i receive error as method name expected.What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would code it like this:

```
Action<int> an = new Action<int>(Console.WriteLine);
an(3000);
```

Chris

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `Action<int>` expects you to pass a pointer to a function that takes an integer as parameter and returns nothing. What you are passing is not a function but an expression. You could either define an anonymous function or use an existing one:

```
Action<int> an = new Action<int>(t => Console.WriteLine(t));
an(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Action points to a method only not to any parameters.

You can then use it like this to invoke the action:

```
Action<int> action = new Action<int>(Console.WriteLine);
action.Invoke(3000);
```